# unexpected token , in jsx of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Trying to render some jsx using seperate functions:

```
renderCheckbox(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Checkbox
                    checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
                    increaseArea="-10%"
                    label="Checkbox"
                  />
            )
            </div>
      }

      renderRadioBtn(){
        return(
            <div>                     
                  <Radio
                    radioClass="iradio_square-blue"
                    increaseArea="-10%"
                    label="Radio, defaultChecked disabled"
                    defaultChecked
                    disabled
                  />
                  </div>
        )

      }
```

I don't see anything wrong but I can't compile my 2 function above. The error in my console showed this

```
Unexpected token, expected , (75:3)
  73 |          )
  74 |          </div>
> 75 |    }
     |    ^
  76 | 
  77 |    renderRadioBtn(){
  78 |      return(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis was in the wrong place. Here's the fix:

```
renderCheckbox(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Checkbox
                    checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
                    increaseArea="-10%"
                    label="Checkbox"
                  />

            </div>
        )
      }

      renderRadioBtn(){
        return(
            <div>                     
                  <Radio
                    radioClass="iradio_square-blue"
                    increaseArea="-10%"
                    label="Radio, defaultChecked disabled"
                    defaultChecked
                    disabled
                  />
                  </div>
        )

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this: end bracket is missing:

```
renderCheckbox(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Checkbox
                    checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
                    increaseArea="-10%"
                    label="Checkbox"
                  />
            </div>
            )

      }
```